# Wrong use of minimal polynomial function in MAGMA?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, math-software, minimal-polynomials, magma-cas

I wrote the following MAGMA code

```
K := pAdicField(3, 100);
R<x> := PolynomialRing(K);
f := x^4 - 3*x^2 + 18;
L := SplittingField(f);

r27 := Roots(x^2 - (-2/7), L)[1][1];
alpha := Roots(f, L)[1][1];
imalpha := (2*alpha^2 - 3)*r27 / alpha;

d := alpha + imalpha;
b := alpha*d;
c := -2*alpha*d/(alpha+imalpha);
a := imalpha*c;

beta := 4*a^3*b - 6*a^2*c*d - 6*a*b*c^2 + 72*c^3*d;
R<x> := PolynomialRing(L);
Roots(x^2 - beta,L);
```

The output shows that the element $\beta$ defined there has no roots in the field $L$ (which is also defined in the code).

Next, I define $L_1$ to be the extension defined by the polynomial $x^2 - \beta$ (since it has degree $2$, I can also take the splitting field of this polynomial):

```
g := x^2 - beta;
L1 := SplittingField(g);
```

Next I define $\gamma$ to be a square root of $\beta$ (i.e. $L_1=L(\gamma)$). Now I am interested in studying the extension $L_1/K$ (and not $L_1/L$). In particular, I would like to compute the Galois group of $L_1/K$.

Since there is no easy way for MAGMA to compute the Galois group of $L_1/K$, my approach was to

- compute the minimal polynomial of $\gamma$ over $K$ (which we call $h$ here),
- take the splitting field of $f \cdot h$ and
- derive the field $L_1$ from this splitting field.

So I started to write the following code:

```
gamma := Roots(g,L1)[1][1];
R<x> := PolynomialRing(K);
h := MinimalPolynomial(gamma,K);
```

If this minimal polynomial function works, it should give us $h(\gamma) = 0$. However, if I type this

```
IsWeaklyZero(Evaluate(h, gamma));
```

then I get **false**.

Could you please explain to me what went wrong here? And is there an alternative approach to my problem?

Comment: Looks like rounding error to me, given that `Evaluate(h, gamma)` gives a result that's *almost* zero.

Comment: @DanielHast: But shouldn't IsWeaklyZero(Evaluate(h, gamma)) give True then? Or is the rounding error really that big?

Comment: What result do you get for `Evaluate(h, gamma)`? When I ran the code, I got something like `$.1*L.1^206 + O(L.1^208)`, which is very very close to zero but doesn't quite satisfy the condition of `IsWeaklyZero`; my best guess is that this is just due to rounding error in the construction of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: I get the same result but was not sure what this .1*L.1^206 part is (probably something non-zero). I hope it is still possible to compute the Galois group of $L_1/K$ despite the rounding error...

By the way, how do you write source codes in the comments? (I usually use Ctrl+K in my posts but this does not work in the comments)

Comment: You can surround the code with backticks (`) to get the monospace font.